# How to run python tkinter at start

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to start my GUI app wrote in python with tkinter at start my Rpi, I set the start method  in the rc.local like this:

```
sudo bash -c 'python /home/pi/Desktop/appPython/good.py > /home/pi/Desktop/good.log 2>&1' &
```

But the app doesn't start and I get the next error in the log:

I

```
no display found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/appPython/good.py", line 10, in <module>
    root=Tk()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2023, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't connect to display ":0.0"
```

I select the display in my code with this method:

```
from tkinter import *
import sys
import os

if os.environ.get('DISPLAY', '')=='':
    print('no display found')
    os.environ.__setitem__('DISPLAY',':0.0')
```

I tried with DISPLAY=:0 and :0.0 with the same result. If I do

```
echo $DISPLAY
```

The result is

```
:0.0
```

Which can be the problem? How can I solve it?

Comment: The problem is that `rc.local` (which is NOT a recommended way of starting programs on boot - search up Systemd) gets run before the desktop has "initialized." So tkinter can't make a window and therefore fails. For a quick, hacky solution, do a `import time` and `time.sleep(10)` before the rest of your script. You may need to adjust the delay.

Comment: Thanks, but with the time.sleep(10) it doesn't work either, is there any possibility for made it work with rc.local?

Comment: Is the traceback still the same even with the time.sleep? Also can you edit your question to include the code with the sleep? (And the traceback)